# SQL subquery - Valores replicados

Tags: sql

estou trabalhando com 3 tabelas, a tabela FORNECED contem o nome e codigo dos fornecedores e as outras duas tabelas possuem os dados que quero trabalhar. O problema se encontra quando tento fazer um loop para poder utilizar as sub-querys. Pois se reparar na tabela o resultador total = 3 e o resultado com filtro é 6. Não tem sentido, pois não exite 6 valores.

```
SELECT F.RASSOC,
(SELECT COUNT(DTENG) 
FROM PARHLISE 
WHERE FORNECE = F.CODIGO) AS TOTAL_PARHLISE,

(SELECT COUNT(P.DTENG) 
FROM PARHLISE AS P
INNER JOIN HISTLISE AS H ON H.FORNECE = P.FORNECE
WHERE P.FORNECE = F.CODIGO AND P.DTENG > H.DTEMI) AS PARHLISE_ATRASO

FROM FORNECED AS F
LEFT JOIN PARHLISE AS PH ON PH.FORNECE = F.CODIGO
LEFT JOIN PARCLISE AS PC ON PC.FORNECE = F.CODIGO
GROUP BY F.CODIGO, F.RASSOC
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Note que você está fazendo uma junção e se houver mais de um registro em HISTLISE para o mesmo FORNECE então poderão ocorrer duplicidades. Talvez não seja o caso de você utilizar junção para sua condição.

Comment: Mas sem a junção eu não obtenho o dado que só existe na histlise

Comment: Você utiliza o `H.DTEMI`, você precisa do valor de DTEMI de TODOS os registros da `HISTLISE` que fazem ligação ao `FORNEECD`? Coloque a estrutura da tabela e o objetivo com essa query, talvez com isso alguém pode enxergar uma forma mais fácil de fazer isso ao invés dessa query.

Comment: por que você está utilizando os LEFT JOIN? não poderia ser somente SELECT F.RASSOC, (SELECT COUNT(DTENG) FROM PARHLISE WHERE FORNECE = F.CODIGO) AS TOTAL_PARHLISE,
(SELECT COUNT(P.DTENG) 
FROM PARHLISE AS P INNER JOIN HISTLISE AS H ON H.FORNECE = P.FORNECE WHERE P.FORNECE = F.CODIGO AND P.DTENG > H.DTEMI) AS PARHLISE_ATRASO
FROM FORNECED AS F

Answer (score 0):

Teste substituir esta junção apenas pela verificação se existe registro em HISTLISE que satisfaça a condição:

```
(SELECT COUNT(P.DTENG) FROM PARHILISE AS P
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM HISTLISE AS H WHERE P.FORNECE = F.CODIGO AND P.DTENG > H.DTEMI)) AS PARHLISE_ATRASO
```